# Understanding Holomorphic Fucntions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Hey I'm new to complex analysis and I'm a bit lost with Holomorphic functions and what to do for questions like these:

Let $$ u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 $$
Is $u$ the real part of a holomorphic function $f$? If so, find $f$. If
not, explain why not

I just made a basic function but what does it mean find $x$ and what would a function that's not holomorphic look like? 
Thanks

EDIT:
$u(x,y)$ is the real part, since $f$ is a holomorphic function, this means that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations 
$$ \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} $$
$$ \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} = - \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} $$

therefore $$ \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = 2x \quad\text{meaning}\quad \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} = 2x $$

and $$ \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} = 2y \quad\text{meaning}\quad  \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} = -2y $$

$$ \int \frac {\partial v} {\partial y}\,dy  = i \int 2x\,dy = 2ixy $$

$$ \int \frac {\partial v} {\partial x}\,dy = -i \int 2y\,dx = -2ixy $$

Then I'm not too sure where to go with it

Comment: See the Cauchy Riemann equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations A function is holomorphic (i.e. analytic in the complex plane) if and only if these equations hold. You should be able to construct the holomorphic function using these equations and the given real part $u$, if such a function exists.

Comment: @poirot Thanks for responding!  would you mind checking out my edit?

Answer (score 1):

The real (and imaginary) part of a holomorphic function is *harmonic*, i.e. $u''_{xx} + u''_{yy} = 0$. (This follows from differentiating Cauchy-Riemann's equations, but I'm confident it's also in your textbook.) Your given function is **not** harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a function that is not holomorphic (i.e. not analytic in the complex plane) is $f(z)=\bar{z}$.

Suppose $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is holomorphic, then $f$ must satisfy the [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) equations (Recall that if $z=x+iy$, then $\bar{z}=x-iy$)

Writing $z=x+iy$, then $f(z)=f(x,y)=x-iy=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=-y$. Then, $u_x=1$, $u_y=0$, $v_x=0$, and $v_y=-1$.

The CR equations below,
$$u_x=v_y\text{ and }u_y=-v_x,$$ must be satisfied.

Substituting our values for $f$ we obtain straight away

$$1=-1,$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $f(z)$ is not holomorphic.